# php code for disabling print screen

Tags: php

I have a website where the users can login and use the contents of the site. I want to disable the print screen so that the users cannot store or download the content from my website. Can anyone help me with disabling the print screen option using php?

Comment: Only way possible, put the following at the top of your file: `<?php exit();`

Comment: PHP runs on the server. By the time the browser displays the page, it is out of the loop. If you want to do something like this, you need to use Javascript or CSS. But the user can easily override it, since it's client-side.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the print screen key of the user's keyboard, I'm sorry that is an interaction between your user and their browser. It has nothing to do with PHP.

If something on your site is truly private, don't put it online, that is the safest option.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable print screen using php. But you can use javascript to do the same. Try the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    function clp_clear() {
        var content=window.clipboardData.getData("Text");
        if (content==null) {
            window.clipboardData.clearData();
        }
        setTimeout("clp_clear();",1000);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload='clp_clear()'>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Even if that code worked (it won't in any sane browser) this is basically worthless. What about tools that take a screenshot without the clipboard? Like the shortcut in OS X?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara It is still one of the solution rather than your "technologically impossible" statements.

Comment: It's technologically impossible to truly prevent the capture anything you send to them. All this is is a cheap trick that doesn't even work in modern browsers. Does this even work in IE, which is the only browser with this API? I'm pretty sure even old IE did not allow clipboard access outside a user event (it would be a gaping security issue). In modern browsers all it will do is add an error to the console every second.